# Что является состоянием в чат-боте?

Tags: шаблоны-проектирования, конечные-автоматы

Для реализации чат-бота предлагается использовать паттерн "Состояние". Хорошо, если состояний небольшое количество (например, пункты меню), то их реализация в коде проблем не вызывает.
Однако рассмотрим следующую задачу - мы пишем текстовую РПГ (очевидно, пошаговую). Каждый переход с локации на локацию (аналогично переходам по пунктам меню) - смена состояния. Но таких состояний могут быть тысячи.
Как быть в этом случае, **что** является состоянием?

Comment: А что вас смущает в тысяче состояний?

Comment: Вообще идея того, что состояний может быть так много. Грубо говоря, если состояние является функцией от множества параметров, ничего не мешает абстрагироваться еще больше и состоянием считать не нахождением на локации, а состояние пользователя (в пути, в бою, ничего не делает и пр.), а локацию - параметром функции определения состояния функции.